# ReactJS mutating props

Tags: reactjs

I'm experiencing mutating props in a component.

```
  handleSave(state) {
    console.log(this.props.data, 'BEFORE');
    let visible = [];
    Object.entries(state).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (value === true) {
        visible.push(key);
      }
    });
    this.setState(curState => ({
      ...curState,
      visibleColumns: visible,
    }),() =>
    console.log(this.props.data, 'AFTER'))
  }
```

The method itself is supposed to toggle the visibility of a column. While the column indeed disappears as expected, it gets removed from the props.data, too, making the whole checkbox disappear in result. 
The props.data is used in a child component to display all columns.

The constructor of the Component looks like this:

```
class OutlierPlanningGroups extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visibleColumns: ["NAME", "CALLS", "EMAILS", "CHATS", "NEW1", "NEW2"],
      displayData: this.props.data,
    };
    this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this);
    this.getVisible = this.getVisible.bind(this);
  }
```

I must be missing something basic, as props in general should be immutable - yet for me, with every 'handleSave', the props.data gets smaller and smaller. Any general advice for what errors to look for is much appreciated (cannot paste the whole code unfortunately).

Thanks!

Comment: `displayData: this.props.data` - any change to displayData object will affect your props.data. assign a copy instead if you want props to be immutable

Comment: I tried this with the following, but I'm still getting the same erroneous behavior where the this.props.data is changing with every click of the save button:
displayData: Object.assign([], this.props.data)